# javascript closures : fails with dynamicly storing groups in object

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a dc.js program which runs fine when I give separate names to dc groups

```
var group1 = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.dd; });
var group2 = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.count; });
```

but when I do

```
    var groups = {};
    var columns   = ["dd","count"];

    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
        var col = columns[i]
        groups[col] = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d[col]; });
    }
```

it only remembers the last column and replaces other charts with last chart.

How should I solve this issue

Comment: also [don't enumerate arrays with for-in-loops, but iterate them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is one that comes up all the time in JavaScript. Your variable "col" is scoped to the function where that `for` loop lives, and so it's shared by the two anonymous functions passed into the "reduceSum()" function.

The solution is to interpose *another* function to provide a distinct copy of the column name.  (Also, you should not use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
  (function( columnName ) {
    group[ columnName ] = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d[columnName]; });
  })( columns[i] );
}
```

Comment: With all respect, is it really necessary to answer this for the 1000th time? A closevote would be more helpful.

Comment: sorry for repetition closed it

Comment: @thg435 well the thing about this issue is that once you "get it", all the myriad manifestations look alike. However, *before* the light goes on, they don't, so other questions about the same topic may not clear up the confusion because the OP may not be able to see the similarity. I wish it were otherwise.